Extract Direct Text Under Beautiful Soup Tag Element
This is blueprint for a recursive function im going to make
def extract_list_items(list):
    items = []

    for each item in main_list:
        if item is list:
            if item has string:
                items.append([string] + extract_list_items(list))
            else:
                items.append(extract_list_items(list))
        else for normal text:
            items.append(normal text)
    return items

Input is a beautiful soup list tag.
Example list:
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>
        Item 3
        <ul>
            <li>Subitem 1</li>
            <li>Subitem 2</li>
        </ul>
        Item 3.1
    </li>
</ul>

When parsing through the list item:
<li>
    Item 3
    <ul>
        <li>Subitem 1</li>
        <li>Subitem 2</li>
    </ul>
    Item 3.1
</li>

I want the output as:
[
    'Item 3',
    [
        'Subitem 1',
        'Subitem 2'
    ],
    'Item 3.1'
]

How do I add the functionality that to extract direct stripped text under list item? In right order as well.
I have tried using tag.text, result wasn't as I expected, it returned along with the string under nested child list.
Strings could have empty new line and white spaces, splitting at new line isn't an option

Your expected output mixes types--not a good idea. All future code that consumes it will be littered with isinstance calls. Better to use a nested list/dict structure with explicit value: and children: keys.

I agree with ggorlen, your output mixes types, and you didn't specify how to handle other nested tags, and what about newlines and breaks?

This gives the expected output for you input, but you mind find the result structure annoying to use (mixed types, lost context for <li> tags), so you might want to reconsider it.
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, element


def walk(ul):
    result = []

    for li in ul.select(":scope > li"):
        nested = []

        for child in li.children:
            if isinstance(child, element.NavigableString):
                nested.append(child.text.strip())
            else:
                nested.append(walk(child))

        if len(nested) == 1:
            result.append(nested[0])
        else:
            result.append(nested)

    return result


if __name__ == "__main__":
    html = """
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>
            Item 3
            <ul>
                <li>Subitem 1</li>
                <li>Subitem 2</li>
            </ul>
            Item 3.1
        </li>
    </ul>"""
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    print(json.dumps(walk(soup.select_one("ul")), indent=4))

Output:
[
    "Item 1",
    "Item 2",
    [
        "Item 3",
        [
            "Subitem 1",
            "Subitem 2"
        ],
        "Item 3.1"
    ]
]

Here's another option that creates a more usable structure:
def walk(ul):
    result = []

    for li in ul.select(":scope > li"):
        nested = []
        result.append(nested)

        for child in li.children:
            if isinstance(child, element.NavigableString):
                nested.append({"value": child.text.strip()})
            else:
                nested.append({"children": walk(child)})

    return result

Output:
[
  [
    {
      "value": "Item 1"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "value": "Item 2"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "value": "Item 3"
    },
    {
      "children": [
        [
          {
            "value": "Subitem 1"
          }
        ],
        [
          {
            "value": "Subitem 2"
          }
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "value": "Item 3.1"
    }
  ]
]

You can optionally nest this in a top-level "children": [...] list.
This is more verbose, but doesn't lose information from the original and is easier to traverse and work with.
Another option is to separate the two different types of <li>s: ones with children, and ones without, so you'll have fewer one-element lists. Something like:
[
  {"value": "Item 1"},
  {"value": "Item 2"},
  {
    "values": [
      {"value": "Item 3"},
      {
        "values": [
          {"value": "Subitem 1"},
          {"value": "Subitem 2"}
        ]
      },
      {"value": "Item 3.1"}
    ]
  }
]

This solves the mixed-type problem (mixed keys are still slightly non-ideal, but this is pretty unavoidable), but here <li> and <ul> aren't differentiated.
